# gzip without server support?

Tags: http, compression, gzip, node.js, http-compression

I have written a CSS server which does minimization and basic parsing/var replacement. The server is using node.js.

I am wanting to gzip my response from this server. As told in IRC, node.js does not currently have a gzip lib, so I am attempting to do it manually from the command line (as I am only gzipping when not in cache).

I am pushing the file data out to a temp file and then using exec to call `'gzip -c -9 -q ' + tempFile`. I get the compressed data back correctly (it seems), and send the proper `Content-Encoding` header as `'gzip'`, but Chrome reports:

`Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error`.

Also, some independent gzip testers online fail as well (not just Chrome).

I'm assuming this is something simple I do not know about generating gzip blocks for browsers, seeing as I have never tried to do it manually.

Any assistance would be helpful. The server is blazing fast, but I need to gzip the content to get the best performance for end users.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I have verified my `Content-Length` is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated the Content-Length to match the gzipped size? It seems like that might screw up the decoding.

Comment: The content is being gzipped _before_ it's sent to the browser. How would the browser not have the correct length? However, I will try that. I'm desperate. :)

Comment: His point is that if your server indicated the pre-compression length as the header, you'd have an illegal HTTP response.

You can easily examine the headers with Fiddler or similar.

Comment: Ok that did not fix it unfortunately.

Comment: It was another bug blocking the result, but this did actually end up being the problem. Long story I will not bore you with, but thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Node is still bleeding edge and seems not yet to have a good handling of binary data.

[Node's string encodings](http://nodejs.org/api.html#_encodings) are ascii, binary and utf8. [...] "binary" only look[s] at the **first 8 bits** of the 16bit JavaScript string characters. The problem is that strings according to ECMA are 16bit character strings. If you use UTF-8 (it's the default) there is some normalization when reading into the string, and this corrupts gzip. If you use ascii, it obviously won't work.

It will work if you use **binary encoding *both* reading and writing**. The upper 8 bits of a Javascript string character just are not being used. If not, try to send the files directly to client without any loading into Javascript strings, perhaps with the help of a proxy server in front of Node.

I myself hope that Google's V8 engine implements a true binary string datatype, something like this proposal http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/648a0f5ed2c95211/ef89acfe538931a1?lnk=gst&q=binary+type#ef89acfe538931a1

CommonJS is also proposing [Binary/B](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Binary/B), and since Node tries to follow CommonJS, there is some hope for the future.

**Edit** I just discovered the [net2 branch](http://github.com/ry/node/tree/net2) of node which contains a binary buffer (see src/node_buffer.h). It is part of a complete overhaul of network it seems.

Comment: My problem actually turned out to be a content-length issue, but was blocked by another devious issue. However you are right, V8 needs to get this stuff implemented, and quickly! :) Thanks for the response.

Comment: Node merged the net2 branch. You can use binary data with Buffer in buffer.js.

Comment: @spot so is the original question still valid?

Comment: @ordnungswidrig Not exactly. Having other issues now. :P